# Is there a way commenting out search terms ? C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

is there a way in  Visual Studios 2015 to comment out every single line that contains my search term?

Example:

1.)I lookup for the word "apple"

2.) >>>> every line that contains the term "apple" will be commented out automatically

Comment: Sounds like that would lead to a few compilation issues, no? What's wrong with finding usages, and then using that result set to change what you need to?

Comment: Have you tried search / replace with regular expressions? Without trying it directly I believe the pattern to search for ^(.*apple.*)$ and then replace with //$1

Answer (score 2):

**Find and Replace -> Replace in Files**

- **Find what:** \b.*apple[^\r\n]*
- **Replace with:** //$&
- **Look in:** Current Document
- **Find options:** Use Regular Expressions

[image]

Comment: No problem, Feel free to Upvote + Accept the answer.